# Binding sub types on the rendering host

Tags: jss, components, rendering-host

I've had a requirement to build a new header menu that can contain different types of columns as sub menus. I've built this out in Sitecore templates roughly as follows:

Top Level Menu Option
Menu Column
Menu Column With Links (base template = Menu Column)
Menu Column With Images (base template = Menu Column)

I've built my C# classes/models in a similar configuration so that "Top Level Menu Option" has a property called children which is of type `List<MenuColumn>`.

When this is serialized with a custom `RenderingContentsResolver` and outputted by the Content Delivery server, I can see that regardless of whether a "Column With Links" or "Column With Images" is added to the `List<MenuColumn>` all relevant fields are included.

My problem is that on the `ASP.NET Core RenderingHost`, when `IViewModelBinder.Bind<T>(ViewContext)` is called, only the parent class fields are bound/deserialized...

I'm not sure if there's something wrong with my logic/architecture or some other way to do this...

I've tried using interfaces/abstract classes but this results in null values after binding.

I considered writing a custom implementation of `IViewModelBinder` but this seems like a lot of work and there's no documentation on how Sitecore has implemented their instance or how it could be extended.

Manually deserializing the response using NewtonSoft also seems messy/risky.

My current feeling is that, rather than extending MenuColumn, I could add 2 properties to the class, one for each sub type, and populate one of these, leaving the other as null, but this seems very hacky.

Is there a recommended method/solution for handling this kind of scenario?

Thanks,

Daniel